# How to add a manifest file to C# with dotnet-cli/vscode?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, manifest, runas

I'm trying to add a manifest file to my C# project, but all the answers/solutions I find say that I should right click on the C# project in Visual Studio. I use Visual Studio Code so I can't really do that. does anyone have a solution?

I need the manifest file to ask for admin rights on runtime. I found a lot of answers to that, my only problem is that I can't add a manifest file.

Comment: Would this one help? https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest

Comment: kinda, i have it now but i can't figure out how to create/edit the manifest file with it

Answer (score 2):

I had a same issue -HTH ;):

1. At the same directory of your `.csproj` file click on *"New File..."*
2. Name your file to: `app.manifest`
3. Copy below code (The default app.manifest content) in it:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
     <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
       <security>
         <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
           <!-- UAC Manifest Options
                If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
                requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

           <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
           <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
           <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

               Specifying requestedExecutionLevel element will disable file and registry virtualization. 
               Remove this element if your application requires this virtualization for backwards
               compatibility.
           -->
           <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
         </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
     </trustInfo>

     <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
       <application>
         <!-- A list of the Windows versions that this application has been tested on and is
              is designed to work with. Uncomment the appropriate elements and Windows will 
              automatically selected the most compatible environment. -->

         <!-- Windows Vista -->
         <!--<supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />-->

         <!-- Windows 7 -->
         <!--<supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />-->

         <!-- Windows 8 -->
         <!--<supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />-->

         <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
         <!--<supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />-->

         <!-- Windows 10 -->
         <!--<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />-->

       </application>
     </compatibility>

     <!-- Indicates that the application is DPI-aware and will not be automatically scaled by Windows at higher
          DPIs. Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications are automatically DPI-aware and do not need 
          to opt in. Windows Forms applications targeting .NET Framework 4.6 that opt into this setting, should 
          also set the 'EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing' setting to 'true' in their app.config. -->
     <!--
     <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
       <windowsSettings>
         <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
       </windowsSettings>
     </application>
     -->

     <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
     <!--
     <dependency>
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity
             type="win32"
             name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
             version="6.0.0.0"
             processorArchitecture="*"
             publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
             language="*"
           />
       </dependentAssembly>
     </dependency>
     -->

   </assembly>
   ```
4. Now you can edit it; As commented in the default file you can use three levels for `requestedExecutionLevel` tag e.g.:

   ```xml
   <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
   ```
5. After saving that, you should add it to your project by adding below tag to your `.csproj` file anywhere under first `PropertyGroup` tag:

   ```xml
     <PropertyGroup>
       <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
     </PropertyGroup>
   ```